# Class template member specialization

Tags: c++, specialization, class-template

I'm specializing member functions of a template class in a header file like so:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Test
{
    void Print() { }
};

template<>
void Test<int>::Print()
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}
```

Is it correct to put the specialization in a header file (without it being inline), or should it be in a cpp file? It compiles fine as shown above (using VS2012), but I'm rather surprised I don't get multiple definition linker errors.

Comment: I do get a linker error, if I include this code in two different files and actually use `Test<int>::Print` (using g++4.8.1).

Comment: No linker error in VS2013. (Not even a warning or anything, even if the two definitions are different.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODR requires exactly one definition for non-inline functions that are *ODR-used* (that roughy means, for functions, being potentially called).

Quoting n3485, [basic.def.odr]

> <sup>4</sup> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of
>   every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that
>   program; no diagnostic required.

Then, there's an exception for *templates* (i.e. not for functions):

> <sup>6</sup> There can be more than one definition of a class type [...], class template, non-static function template, static data member
>   of a class template, **member function of a class template, or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not specified** in a program provided that [...]

[emphasis mine]

An explicit specialization of a template is not a template. For example, an explicitly specialized class template is a class (with a strange name). Therefore, your assumption is correct and multiple definitions for explicitly specialized members of class templates violate the ODR.

With g++4.8.1, I even get a linker error in such a program; note that I have ODR-used the function. No diagnostic is required for a violation of the ODR.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the specialisation in the header file is the canonical form (as `boost` does), it doesn't violate the ODR.

Comment: Could you provide an example of where boost does this? I wonder as the ODR has an explicit exception for template specializations "for which some template parameters are not specified", but not for *explicit (=full) specializations*, as far as I can see.